# Remove double quotes using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have to remove the double quotes if it is directly followed with element `<remove>some text</remove>`. For example

> This is to be interpreted in "about verb"
>   accordance with something "some of plants" and so
>   on
>
> Should be
>
> This is to be interpreted in about verb accordance
>   with something some of plants and so on

```
<p>This is to be interpreted in "<remove>about verb</remove>" accordance with something "<remove>some of plants</remove>" and so on</p>
```

Should be

```
<p>This is to be interpreted in <remove>about verb</remove> accordance with something <remove>some of plants</remove> and so on</p>
```

Comment: which version of XSLT you are using?

Comment: show XML example and desired output format.

Comment: "<remove>about verb</remove>" should be <remove>about verb</remove>. The parent element is <p>. The content of remove element may varies.

Comment: Please answer the question about your processor version.

Answer (score 3):

In **XSLT 1.0**, this could be handled by:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:variable name="s" select="preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::remove] and starts-with(., '&quot;')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="e" select="following-sibling::node()[1][self::remove] and substring(., string-length(.))='&quot;'"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1 + $s, string-length(.) -$s -$e)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Here I found the below validation error
Arithmetic operator is not defined for arguments of types (xs:integer, xs:boolean)

Comment: Here you can see the above working with no problems: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9h

Comment: @Reegan - You should have mentioned the version in your question, but it looks like you are using an XSLT 2.0 processor. All you need to do then is cast the booleans to ints, and all is good. See https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9h/1 for example. (And you can also make use of `ends-with` for the second variable).

Comment: Good answer. Ussing `preceding-sibling::node()[1]` instead of `preceding-sibling::*[1]` has the side effects of making comment or PI break the replecement.

Answer (score 0):

For 2.0 you can use fn:replace():

```
replace(//p,'&quot;','')
```

Comment: No need to remove quote in all conditions. But only if it is in before remove element and after remove element. Also both quote should be there in the remove element